# Why is the ( ) mandatory in the SQL statement "select * from gifts INNER JOIN sentgifts using (giftID);"?

Tags: sql, mysql, inner-join, using

Why is the ( ) mandatory in the SQL statement

```
select * from gifts INNER JOIN sentgifts using (giftID);
```

?  The (  ) usually is for specifying grouping of something.  But in this case, are we supposed to be able to use 2 or more field names...?  in the example above, it can be all clear that it is 1 field, is it just that the parser is not made to bypass the (  ) when it is all clear?  (such as in the language Ruby).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can specify multiple columns inside of the using clause like below.

```
using(col_1,col_2,col_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact specify a **list of columns**, check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html).

And it's mandatory because syntax exceptions blow the parser and are bad for performance.

That said one could argue that *USING* itself is already just **syntactic sugar**, it's just a shortcut of specifying a join with the normal *ON* syntax in case the column names are the same for the joined tables.

Since you can join *ON* multiple columns *USING* is just doing the same thing.

The following **statements are** therefore **equivalent**:

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, A.c3 FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B 
ON A.c1 = B.c1 
ON A.c2 = B.c2 
ON A.c3 = B.c3
```

and

```
SELECT A.c1, A.c2, A.c3 FROM TABLE_A A
JOIN TABLE_B B 
USING (c1,c2,c3)
```